# angular4 typescript classes, 3 methods to create an instance, tutorial hero

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I'm practicing typescript with angular, and I need to see how to work with 3 different methods to create an instance. I took like the example angular hero tutorial to create the first instance: hero1, and but I don't get that hero2 and hero3 works. I'm trying print 3 hero's name on the template.

the code:

app.component.js

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
hero: Hero = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Flash'
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>Hero1: {{hero.name}} , Hero2:  {{hero2.name}} , Hero3: {{hero3.name}}</h2>`,
})
export class AppComponent    {
  public hero2: Hero;
  public hero3;

  title = 'Tour of Heros';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.hero2  =  {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Superman'
    };
    this.hero3  = new (3, 'Spiderman') ;
  }
}
```

Here the code solved using 3 methods (thanks to the answers):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>Hero1: {{hero.name}} , Hero2:  {{hero2.name}} , Hero3: {{hero3.name}}</h2>`,
})
export class AppComponent    {
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Flash'
  }
  title = 'Tour of Heros';
  public hero2: Hero;
  public hero3: Hero;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.hero2  =  {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Superman'
    };
    this.hero3  = new Hero (3, 'Spiderman') ;
  }
}
```

Comment: this `this.hero3  = new (3, 'Spiderman') ;` isn't a valid syntax. Perhaps you want to instantiate a new `Hero`? So it'd be the following: `this.hero3  = new Hero(3, 'Spiderman') ;`... and also you have to define the constructor for `Hero` *class*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is something like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  // This allows you to make the call `new Hero(1, 'Flash')` for example
  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

// Your Hero class could also look like this because TypeScript is awesome
// export class Hero {
//   constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }
// }

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>
  <!-- if you want all of the heroes to appear in 
  the same <h2>...</h2> tag as you had it, this is
  one way you can do it.  `ng-template` ends up not
  appearing in the DOM -->
  <ng-template *ngFor="let hero of heroes">Hero{{hero.id}}: {{hero.name}}</ng-template>
</h2>

<!-- I'd suggest changing your template to something like this: -->
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2 *ngFor="let hero of heroes">{{hero.id}}: {{hero.name}}</h2>
<!-- ... so that each hero gets its own <h2>...</h2> tag -->
`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[]; // A bucket-o-heroes (array, rather) that can grow and shrink in size as you see fit.
  title = 'Tour of Heros';

  // This gets called when the component is initialized
  ngOnInit() {
    // This populates the public property of the AppComponent that is an array of Heroes
    this.heroes = [
      new Hero(1, 'Flash'),
      new Hero(2, 'Superman'),
      new Hero(3, 'Spiderman')
    ]
  }
}
```

You'll want to use an array so that when your app is running in someone's browser, you might want them to be able to add more heroes in real time, so there could be a method that appends a hero they created to the array.  The way you had your code doesn't allow for more heroes to be added because the three of the them were referenced with individual public properties of the component.

You'll also need a constructor in your Hero class if you want to make new ones while passing in the `id` and the `name`.

Hope this helps!  Have fun with Angular!

Comment: thanks,   but  i'm just trying to use different variables with differents methods, hero1 is accord to angular tutorial, how hero2 can works with this method?

Comment: thanks , i've pasted my solution below my question using your device

Comment: @DDave, I'm not sure what you mean by use different variables with different methods.  But you could always pull out the hero you want from the array, assign it to a local variable in the method you need to use it in, and go from there.  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array of Hero objects like

```
this.heroes = [
      new Hero(1, 'XXX'),
      new Hero(2, 'YYY'),
      new Hero(3, 'ZZZ')
    ];
```

if you are using this approach you must have a constructor in your hero component class that initializes the object .

After this using ngFor i:e Structural Directive you can print the result in the template.

like

```
<div *ngFor =  "let hero of heroes">
    {{hero.id}} -- {{hero.name}}
</div>
```

or the next approach will to use like an normal object array .

```
this.heroes = [
{name: 'XXXX',id : '1'},
{name: 'YYY',id : '2'}
];
```

Please check this link for further angular concepts

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts

Comment: thanks anyway, i've had to mark just one answer like valid

Comment: @DDave you can upvote answers if you feel it is upto mark even for jake accept and upvote his answer